# Cosmos DB indexing policy keepsreverting back to default after few hours into re-indexing

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to update my Cosmos DB collection indexing policy but the new policy keeps reverting back to default policy (I had default policy set till now).

The new policy gets saved successfully and I can see re-indexing reaches 2-3% and then suddenly I see the policy reverting back to default and re-indexing starts again.

I have about 300GBs of data in my collection.

New indexing policy looks like this:

```json
    {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "automatic": true,
        "includedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/someobj1/*"
            },
            {
                "path": "/someattr/?"
            },
            {
                "path": "/somearray/[]/*"
            },
            {
                "path": "/someattr/?"
            },
            {
                "path": "/someothrattr/?"
            },
            {
                "path": "/someoytherarr/[]/*"
            },
            {
                "path": "/someobj/anotherarr/[]/*"
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

AND it keeps reverting back to default policy:

```json
    {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "automatic": true,
        "includedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/*"
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Going to raise a support request for Azure as well as it could be a bug. Is anyone facing similar issue?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to recreate the container in your code?

Comment: No, I am not updating policy through code. I am using portal UI to simply paste new policy and save it for an existing container.

Comment: Please check if you are doing something like this in your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-create-container#dotnet-sql. That might explain why your indexing policy is being overwritten.

Comment: There is no code involved. It's an existing container. I am just updating the indexing policy via portal.

Comment: Ah i see what you meant, and nope. No where in my code i am creating container. It was created manually. So no chance of recreating it with same name.

Comment: Without seeing the actual indexing policy it's hard for anyone to say for sure. If not comfortable sharing here, then support ticket is best route

Comment: Will raise support ticket, Will share insight if we get one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same situation and in my case I realized the indexing policy was reverted back to the default whenever the application was deployed. And the reason is that I am using ARM-Template to deploy Azure resources in the release pipeline where the indexing policy is not defined as part of cosmos container resource. So after adding the indexing policy in the ARM-Template using the guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/manage-with-bicep), I dont loose the indexing policy anymore after each deployment.

Comment: This was the issue in my case too.